# Fingerprint cannot be generated on my gitlab (linux)

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, fingerprint

I tried to add an SSH key to my gitlab.  I pasted my complete key and clicked "add key", but an error appeared:

> Fingerprint cannot be generated

I granted access to `/tmp` dir to git user.

Each click makess a file in `/tmp`, so the problem is somewhere else...

Can you help me?

Comment: You're pasting the content of `id_rsa.pub`?

Comment: yes, I do, it works on other gitlab.

Comment: I tried to upgrade gitlab (v1.6.7 => v7.1.0) but not resolve the problem. I tried to regenerate ssh key for my user, no result more...

Comment: Is it an omnibus gitlab ? Take a look at `/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh` rights, and look if the key you tried to upload appears in `/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: yes it is. "-rw------- 1 git git 0 Jul 23 15:22 authorized_keys" and authorized_keys file is empty...

Comment: https://jxqc.wordpress.com/2014/09/01/gitlab-key-is-invalid-fingerprint-cannot-be-generated/

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem. I regenerated a ssh key without passphrase which worked fine for me